# Mutations using Relay Environment

Tags: react-native, graphql, relayjs

I'm using Relay with React Native and have a problem during login & logout.

After login or logout, Relay keeps the store from the previous user. To solve this I use `Relay.Renderer` and `Relay.Environment`. As in, in each `Renderer` I put singleton object of `Environment`.

The problem is that I previously did a mutation on object of `Relay.Store`, as in 
`Relay.Store.commitUpdate(new CreateProfile(), callback)`.

Now it doesn't work. I guess this is because `Relay.Store` doesn't know anything about server endpoints. But `Relay.Environment` does.

And now I'm using something like this `this.props.relay.commitUpdate(new CreateProfile(), callback)`. It works pretty well when the parent component is wrapped as `Relay.Container`, so it has relay object in props.

But what should I do in components which are not `Relay.Containers` and don't have `Relay` object in props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Relay.Store` is a globally accessible singleton instance of `Relay.Environment` and `Relay.Store.commitUpdate()` updates data in that global environment. But since you're using your own instance of `Relay.Environment`, to update it you need to use `this.props.relay.commitUpdate()`, as you noted. This updates the environment the container was rendered with.

**If need to make mutations from child components of containers**, that are not wrapped in a `Relay.Container`, there are two ways to do that. You could simply pass the `relay` prop to them, so in the render function of your container you would have:

```
<Child relay={this.props.relay} />
```

However, since those plain components are not in a Relay container, they don't currently need to know anything about Relay. If you want to keep them that way, you could write the method that does the update in your container component like this:

```
onCreateProfile = () => {
  this.props.relay.commitUpdate(new CreateProfile());
};
```

and only pass a callback to your child component in `render`:

```
<Child onCreateProfile={this.onCreateProfile} />
```

**If you need to make a mutation from a component that does not have a `Relay.Container` above it in the component hierarchy** at all, you could create the `Relay.Environment` in a shared root component higher up and pass it down using props (or pass a callback using the strategy shown above).